# Ruby Koans not compatible with Ruby 2.0.0?

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-2.0

After successfully upgrading to Ruby 2.0.0's stable release (yay!) I decided to continue on my Koans **Path to Enlightenment**. However, when running the `rake` command within the koans folder, as I normally do, I receive this error:

```
rake
cd koans
/Users/jordanthornquest/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb
/Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:399:in `rescue in meditate': uninitialized constant EdgeCase::Sensei::AssertionError (NameError)
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:407:in `meditate'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:470:in `block in walk'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:481:in `block (3 levels) in each_step'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:479:in `each'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:479:in `block (2 levels) in each_step'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:478:in `each'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:478:in `each_with_index'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:478:in `block in each_step'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:476:in `catch'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:476:in `each_step'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:469:in `walk'
    from /Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/koans/edgecase.rb:491:in `block in <top (required)>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/jordanthornquest/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2...]
/Users/jordanthornquest/programming/ruby-koans/Rakefile:90:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/jordanthornquest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/jordanthornquest/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => default => walk_the_path
```

I also installed a fresh new Koans batch from GitHub today, as well, to assure that that wasn't my problem. Neither worked for me! It still runs great with 1.9.3. It may be worth noting that I also installed Ruby 2.0 via RVM. I made sure to update to the latest RVM before doing so.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a pull request to fix this, but it has not been accepted yet: https://github.com/neo/ruby_koans/pull/84

For now, you can edit line 149 of `src/edgecase.rb` to be:

```
in_ruby_version("1.9", "2.0") do
```

Comment: Cool! Will this need to be edited later on in any case? In other words, will this cause any problems with other applications? Can I leave this code, or should I change it back as soon as Koans has been fixed?

Comment: This change is directly to the Koans code, not to Ruby in general; it won't affect anything outside of Koans. And when they fix it, you can just download the updated code and replace it.